# Swift: Pass array by reference?

Tags: arrays, swift, pass-by-reference

I want to pass my Swift `Array` `account.chats` to `chatsViewController.chats` by reference (so that when I add a chat to `account.chats`, `chatsViewController.chats` still points to `account.chats`). I.e., I don't want Swift to separate the two arrays when the length of `account.chats` changes.

Comment: I ended up just making `account` a global variable and defining the `chats` property of `ChatsViewController` as: `var chats: [Chat] { return account.chats }`.

Comment: ma11hew28, your solution is worthy of an Answer.  You could also add a setter to make chats updateable.  `var chats: [Chat] { get { return account.chats } set { account.chats = newValue } }`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Structs in Swift are passed by value, but you can use the `inout` modifier to modify your array (see answers below). Classes are passed by reference. `Array` and `Dictionary` in Swift are implemented as structs.

Comment: Array is not copied / passed by value in Swift - it has very different behavior in Swift compared to regular struct.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450284/conflicting-definition-of-struct-and-array/24454610#24454610

Comment: @Boon Array is still semantically copied/passed-by-value, but just optimised to use [COW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write).

Comment: And I don't recommend using of `NSArray` because `NSArray` and Swift array have subtle semantic differences (such as reference-type), and that possibly lead you to more bugs.

Comment: This was seriously killing me. I was banging my head why things not working the way.

Comment: What if using `inout` with Structs?

Comment: Wow thank you this helped me a lot, `structs in swift are passed by value`

Answer (score 159):

For function parameter operator we use:
**`let`** (it's default operator, so we can omit **let**) to make a parameter constant (it means we cannot modify even local copy);
**`var`** to make it variable (we can modify it locally, but it wont affect the external variable that has been passed to the function); and
**`inout`** to make it an in-out parameter. In-out means in fact passing variable by reference, not by value. And it requires not only to accept value by reference, by also to pass it by reference, so pass it with **`&`** - `foo(&myVar)` instead of just `foo(myVar)`

So do it like this:

```swift
var arr = [1, 2, 3]

func addItem(_ localArr: inout [Int]) {
    localArr.append(4)
}

addItem(&arr)    
print(arr) // it will print [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

To be exact it's not just a reference, but a real alias for the external variable, so you can do such a trick with any variable type, for example with integer (you can assign new value to it), though it may not be a good practice and it may be confusing to modify the primitive data types like this.

Comment: Please add some context/explanation to your answer.

Comment: This does not really explain how to use array as an instance variable that is referenced not copied.

Comment: I thought inout used a getter and a setter to copy the array to a temporary and then reset it on the way out of the function - i.e. it copies

Comment: Any idea how this is done when declaring a local variable - say a guard that unwraps and optional array. When the unwrapped array is modifies the original array should be modified too, using the guard variable. A possible workaroud would be to pass unwrapped optional to a local function with `inout` parameter but this is weird

Comment: Actually in-out uses copy-in copy-out or call by value result.  However, as an optimization it may use by reference.   "As an optimization, when the argument is a value stored at a physical address in memory, the same memory location is used both inside and outside the function body. The optimized behavior is known as call by reference; it satisfies all of the requirements of the copy-in copy-out model while removing the overhead of copying."

Comment: I dont think so I works what intended question was. I have trying to pass an array to method and I am removing the element. Guess what. orginal array still have those elements.

Comment: In Swift 3, `inout` position has changed, i.e. `func addItem(localArr: inout [Int])`

Comment: Also, `var` is no longer available for function parameter attribute.

Answer (score 29):

Define yourself a `BoxedArray<T>` that implements the `Array` interface but delegates all functions to a stored property.  As such

```
class BoxedArray<T> : MutableCollection, Reflectable, ... {
  var array : Array<T>

  // ...

  subscript (index: Int) -> T { 
    get { return array[index] }
    set(newValue) { array[index] = newValue }
  }
}
```

Use the `BoxedArray` anywhere you'd use an `Array`.  Assigning of a `BoxedArray` will be by reference, it is a class, and thus changes to the stored property, through the `Array` interface, will be visible to all references.

Comment: A bit scary solution :) - not exactly elegant - but it seems it would work.

Comment: Well, it sure is better than falling back to 'Use NSArray' to get 'pass by reference semantics'!

Comment: I just have a feeling defining Array as struct instead of class is language design mistake.

Comment: I agree.  There is also the abomination where `String` is a subtype of `Any` BUT if you `import Foundation` then `String` becomes a subtype of `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 19):

For Swift versions 3-4 (XCode 8-9), use

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]

func addItem(_ localArr: inout [Int]) {
    localArr.append(4)
}

addItem(&arr)
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
var a : Int[] = []
func test(inout b : Int[]) {
    b += [1,2,3,4,5]
}
test(&a)
println(a)
```

???

Comment: I think the question is asking for a means to have _properties_ of two different objects point to the same array. If that's the case, Kaan's answer is correct: one must either wrap the array in a class, or use NSArray.

Comment: right, inout works only for the lifetime of the function body (no closure behaviour)

Comment: Minor nit: it's `func test(b: inout [Int])` ... maybe this is an old syntax; I only got into Swift in 2016 and this answer is from 2014 so maybe things used to be different?

Answer (score 3):

One other option is to have the consumer of the array ask the owner for it as needed. For example, something along the lines of:

```
class Account {
    var chats : [String]!
    var chatsViewController : ChatsViewController!

    func InitViewController() {
        chatsViewController.getChats = { return self.chats }
    }

}

class ChatsViewController {
    var getChats: (() -> ([String]))!

    func doSomethingWithChats() {
        let chats = getChats()
        // use it as needed
    }
}
```

You can then modify the array as much as you like inside the Account class. Note that this doesn't help you if you want to also modify the array from the view controller class.

Answer (score 1):

Using `inout` is one solution but it doesn't feel very swifty to me since arrays are value types. Stylistically I personally prefer to return a mutated copy:

```
func doSomething(to arr: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var arr = arr
    arr.append(3) // or likely some more complex operation
    return arr
}

var ids = [1, 2]
ids = doSomething(to: ids)
print(ids) // [1,2,3]
```

Comment: There is a performance downside to this sort of thing. It uses a tad bit less phone battery to just modify the original array :)

Comment: I respectfully disagree. In this case readability at the call site generally trumps the performance hit. Start with immutable code and then optimize by making it mutable later. There are cases with massive arrays where you are correct but in most apps that's a 0.01% edge case.

Comment: I don't know what you are disagreeing with. There is a performance penalty to copy the array and lesser performance operations do use more CPU and therefore more battery. I think you assumed that I was saying that it is a better solution, which I was not. I was making sure people have all of the information available to make an informed choice.

Comment: Yep, you're correct, there's no question inout is more efficient. I thought you were suggesting that `inout` is universally better because it saves battery. To which I'd say the readability, immutability, and thread safety of this solution are universally better and that inout should only be used as an optimization in those rare cases where the use case warrants it.

Answer (score 1):

use a `NSMutableArray` or a `NSArray`, which are classes

this way you don't need to implment any wraper and can use the build in bridging

```
open class NSArray : NSObject, NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding, NSFastEnumeration
```

Answer (score -1):

Based off of GoZoner's `BoxedArray` answer, I created the class below that worked for me.  I like the freedom of passing around arrays as references (as the other languages I work with do).

```
class MArray<T> : MutableCollection {
    
    var array : Array<T> = Array()
    var count: Int { return array.count }   // getter (without, index func below will be called repeatedly to determine)
    
    func add(_ value: T) {
        array.append(value)
    }

    // MutableCollection requires:
    subscript (index: Int) -> T {
      get { return array[index] }
      set(value) { array[index] = value }
    }
    var startIndex: Int {
        return 0
    }
    var endIndex: Int {
        return array.count
    }
    func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return i+1
    }
}
```