# Conflicting definition of Swift struct and array

Tags: swift

In Swift Programming Language, it says:

1. “all of the basic types in Swift—integers, floating-point numbers, Booleans, strings, **arrays** and dictionaries—**are value types**, and are implemented as structures behind the scenes.”
2. “**structure** instances are **always passed by value**, and class instances are always passed by reference”
3. “If you assign an Array instance to a constant or variable, or pass an Array instance as an argument to a function or method call, the **contents of the array are not copied** at the point that the assignment or call takes place. Instead, both arrays share the same sequence of element values. When you modify an element value through one array, the result is observable through the other.”

Clearly, Swift is contradicting itself when it comes to array.  Is array a value type or reference type?

Comment: My guess would be they're passed as reference type.

Comment: 4. _Swift automatically bridges between the `Array` type and the `NSArray` class._ 5. _Data types that are convertible or can be used interchangeably are referred to as bridged data types._ 6. _You can also cast between a bridged type and its counterpart._ https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html, therefore, the **reference** will be passed over as in the case of `NSArray`.

Comment: @Boon, my comment was very constructive, objective, and based on the official documentation, which I linked to you correctly, because it looked you have not read it before. so, I still no have any idea of what you are talking about as _smarty pants comment_, therefore I can tell you the same: go for it and flat it, if you feel my help offensive.

Comment: @Boon, if you want to make sure the reference will be passed over you have to use `inout` parameters, and pass the reference directly using the `&` prefix.

Comment: @holex Sorry for not being clear.  What I meant was my question is not based on Foundation but in general.  Hence my suggestion that point #4 (and beyond) is not relevant in the context of this discussion.

Answer (score 8):

Array are special cases. They are value types with a special behavior.

At the page where you found the point 3) there are enough information to understand why:

> The assignment and copy behavior for Swift’s Array type is more
>   complex than for its Dictionary type. Array provides C-like
>   performance when you work with an array’s contents and copies an
>   array’s contents only when copying is necessary

and, immediately after you statement:

> Instead, both arrays share the same sequence of element values. When
>   you modify an element value through one array, the result is
>   observable through the other.
>
> For arrays, copying only takes place when you perform an action that
>   has the potential to modify the length of the array.

So, reading these points we understand that:

- array are struct but with a special behavior, the mainly reason is to conserve C-like performance.
- the copy is made only when the length of the copied array is changed

Last thing: remember that, when an array is copied, only value types (structures, enumerations, primitive types) are copied. Objects are not copied, only their references (pointers) are copied

Comment: I understand it's special. Should it be termed reference type or value type, given the definition that struct is value type, but its copying behavior seems more like reference type.

Comment: Since the definition is Struct, they are (semantically talking) value types (although the special behavior)

Answer (score 3):

bases on interferece between **#2** and **#3**, I'm trying to find the answer to your question via an example in practice. it is truly based on *Swift* types only.

I have an `Array` here, and I fill it up with random numbers.

```
var arrayOfNumbers: Array<UInt32> = Array()
for _ in 0..100 {
    arrayOfNumbers.append(arc4random())
}
```

I will check what it returns:

```
let myReturnedArray: Array<UInt32> = self.myReferenceTest(arrayOfNumbers, referenceArray: &arrayOfNumbers)
    
if arrayOfNumbers === myReturnedArray {
    println("(rS)") // returned value is the same instance
} else {
    println("(rD)") // returned value is a different instance
}
```

and I have a test method with two parameters, the first is the `Array` itself, the second one is just the reference of the same `Array`. I'm trying to do different things in that method to see what will happen.

---

## 1st case

```
func myReferenceTest (directory: Array<UInt32, Inuit referenceArray: Array<UInt32) -> Array<UInt32> {
    if directArray === referenceArray {
        println("(pS)") // the same instance...
    } else {
        println("(pD)") // different instance ...
    }
            
    return directArray
}
```

that will print `"(pS)"`, so it looks the **reference** has been passed over as first paramater not the copy of the struct. the consol says `"(rS)"`, the the returned value was the same **reference** and not a copy.

---

## 2nd case

```
func myReferenceTest(directArray: Array<UInt32>, inout referenceArray: Array<UInt32>) -> Array<UInt32> {
    if directArray === referenceArray {
        println("(pS)")
    } else {
        println("(pD)")
    }
    
    directArray[0] = 12
    
    return directArray
}
```

it says still the same `"pS"` and `"rS"`, but if I print the original array's `[0]` element it is updated to `12`, however `directArray` was not an `inout` paremeter at all. the **reference** was passed over, and the reference was returned, and I also called a *non-mutating* method on the array, and I was able to make certain changes.

---

## 3rd case

```
func myReferenceTest(directArray: Array<UInt32>, inout referenceArray: Array<UInt32>) -> Array<UInt32> {
    if directArray === referenceArray {
        println("(pS)")
    } else {
        println("(pD)")
    }

    var myOtherArray = directArray
    myOtherArray.append(arc4random())
    
    return myOtherArray
}
```

the console says `"pS"` but `"rD"` becase I've called a `mutating` method in the `directArray` that caused the array was copied (`O(n)`), and I made the changes on another instance.

---

## 5th case

```
func myReferenceTest(directArray: Array<UInt32>, inout referenceArray: Array<UInt32>) -> Array<UInt32> {
    if directArray === referenceArray {
        println("(pS)")
    } else {
        println("(pD)")
    }

    var myOtherArray = directArray
    myOtherArray.append(arc4random())
    referenceArray = myOtherArray
    
    return myOtherArray
}
```

same as the recent one, but it will say on console `"pS"` and `"rS"` again. so it seems the **reference** was returned and not the copy of the `myOtherArray`.

---

## 6th case

```
func myReferenceTest(directArray: Array<UInt32>, inout referenceArray: Array<UInt32>) -> Array<UInt32> {
    if directArray === referenceArray {
        println("(pS)")
    } else {
        println("(pD)")
    }

    referenceArray.append(arc4random())
    directArray[0] = 12

    return directArray
}
```

it will show `"pS"` and `"rD"` again, and the reference array's first element is `12` and it looks the `directArray` was copied after I've call a `mutating` method on the `referenceArray`. you can check it without doubt: the `referenceArray` is still identical to my original array but the `directArray` is different now.

If I don't return the `directArray` that will be released at all when the method is run out of its scope, becase the copy is created in the method's scope only.

---

## not conclusion but observation instead

it seems the `Array` is always creates a new instance of itself when you call a `mutating` method on it, which is in accordance with the *Swift* documantation about the `mutating` keyword:

> However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to *mutating* behavior for that method. The method can then mutate (that is, change) its properties from within the method, and any changes that it makes are written back to the original structure when the method ends. The method can also assign a completely new instance to its implicit `self` property, and this new instance will replace the existing one when the method ends.

([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Methods.html))

that behaviour is pretty much as same as the *Swift* logic here: the compiler tries to not extend the code with copying of any object until it certainly necessary, which looks – in the case of `Array` at least – happaning when a `mutating` method is called on the object.

you will find more information about which methods of which *Swift* types are `mutating` in the *Swift Standard Library Reference*, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html).

---

nevertheless, even if the `Array` looks to be defined as a *struct*, it defintely behaves like a *class*, because they have some class-level [privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/ClassesAndStructures.html):

> - Type casting enables you to check and interpret the type of a class instance at runtime.
> - Reference counting allows more than one reference to a class instance.

I have not found evidence the rest two privileges of classes, but having these two class-level privilages indicates the `Array` is definitely *more* than a simple `struct`, which makes the statement **#1** ambiguous.

having those prvileges indicates the reference is being passed (logically) in every case.

---

the `Dictionary` is a simpliest case, becase it looks an plain `NSMutableDictionary` behind the scenes, when I ask the class's name via `object_getClassName(...)`, it clearly refers to an instance of a mutable dictionary from Obj-C, which is defintely not a `struct` even if the declaration of `Dictionary` indicates a `struct`.

it is pontless to go further in guessing of what happens in the engine, the compiler is still *Beta* so we don't know how the final compiler will work; evenetually many conspiration-theory can be defined about them (or already hve been), I've tried to focus on the facts only which can be provable during identifying them in background, which may be changed in the future, but those are the facts currently.

Answer (score 1):

**Array are just value types**. That is correct. And it is very likely to use COW([Copy-On-Write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)) to avoid high copying cost of brute-force value-type semantics implementation. So it will be copied only when the new instance is going to be mutated.

There was some trouble with this semantics issue in beta period, but it was eliminated in later betas because having a grey-colored behaviour is insane, and now (Swift version 1.0) it is strictly value type semantics.

Your point #3 is just an explanation about the optimisation --- which is an implementation details meaningful only for optimisations. Forget about implementation details when you thinking about semantics. Just use arrays and dictionaries just like any other value-type stuffs. And remember the implementation details **only when** you need to concern about the performance and optimisation. In most cases, just using is fine in both of semantics or performance perspectives.

BTW, *reference type* means it has automatic/implicit *identity* that can be *referenced*.

Answer (score 0):

Array in swift are value type when i try the following code:

```
var myArray1 = [1, 2, 3]
var myArray2 = myArray1
myArray2 += 4;
println(myArray1);
println(myArray2);
```

It print different value for myArray1 and my Array2. If they share same reference the value must be same.

Comment: Array are special cases, for Arrays the copy takes place only when the lenght is changed (as you did in your example). Try to change the third line in `myArray1[0] = 100` and look the results

Comment: @LombaX It appears that this is no longer the case. When I write `myArray[0] = 100` only the first array changes

Comment: @EliGanem I confirm that this seems changed, even on the manual I cannot find the previous statement about this special case. It seems that now has been changed to "Swift only performs an actual copy behind the scenes when it is absolutely necessary to do so". In the previous release I remember that there was the same example of my post :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Array is struct:

```
struct Array<T> : MutableCollection, Sliceable {...}
```

And all struct are always copied when they are passed around in the code.
Classes are passed by reference.

So the Array are value types.

Comment: Please see Point #3 in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Array is indeed a struct, a value type. However, they went into great lengths to make it behave like a reference type (special copy behaviour, subscripts can modify even constant arrays, they even defined `===` operator especially for arrays!).

This was probably done because of performance reasons but the resulting behavior is buggy and hard to work with.

To quote Apple (https://devforums.apple.com/thread/228695)

> Array semantics were in flux at the time of Beta 1, and have been revised to provide full value semantics like Dictionary and String.  This will be available in later betas.
>
> -Chris

So, we can expect the Array behavior to change greatly in future betas.