# Is it possible to avoid struct mutation in swift?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to have struct behave like an object. F.e.:

```
var arr = [1]
let arr1 = arr 
arr.append(1)
```

I'd like to have arr1 to be the same as arr. Is wrapping into an object the only choice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift: Pass array by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250938/swift-pass-array-by-reference)

Comment: So you don't want to avoid struct mutation. You want to embrace struct mutation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe is one of the fundamental differences in behaviours between structs and objects in Swift.  Structs are always copy by value.  So no, you will have to use an object if you want copy by reference semantics.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @ChrisK's answer, I don't see many practical uses of referencing to the same array from different variables, unless what you want to achieve is to pass it to a function/method - in that case you **can** pass by reference using the `inout` modifier:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3]

func changeArray(inout array: [Int]) {
    array.append(4)
}

changeArray(&array)
```

Read more about [In-Out Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_267)

**Update** You mentioned a very good use case in your comment. And that led me to a solution, which is more a workaround - what's important is that it works.

Use `NSMutableArray` instead of swift arrays. It's a class, so it has all the advantages you are looking for. Example from a playground:

```
var arr: NSMutableArray = [
    NSMutableArray(array: [1, 2, 3])
]

arr[0].addObject(4)
arr[0].replaceObjectAtIndex(0, withObject: -1)
arr // This prints [[-1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: How about having an array of arrays? If I want to change a "row" array I have to re-assign it.

Comment: Good point. That's one of the few cases when it's handy. I think you should make it explicit in your question if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: See updated answer. I think `NSMutableArray` is what you are looking for.