# Swift: Assigning an variable to point to an array (vs copying)

Tags: swift

When we assign an variable to an array, we are copying it, vs actually modifying it.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = a
b.append(4) //1, 2, 3, 4
a //1, 2, 3
```

If I want `b` to point to `a`, how would I do that?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250938/swift-pass-array-by-reference

Comment: Ah! searched for rather long, but did not see that, let me take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are structs and structs are value types. What you're looking for is a reference type. NSMutableArray looks like a better fit than Array. It's a class and a reference type.

Try this code:

```
var a: NSMutableArray = [1, 2, 3]    

var b = a
b.addObject(4) //1, 2, 3, 4
a //1, 2, 3, 4
b //1, 2, 3, 4

let worked = (a === b) // true
```