# return function result to output argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In **objective-c** I can declare a function with an output argument, I suppose that is so called *pass-by-reference*:

```
-(void) doTask(int id, output: (NSArray**)results) {
   …
   results = getResult()
}
```

Then, I can access the `results` to check the output of `doTask()` **outside** the function scope.

In **swift**, is it still valid?

```
func doTask(id:Int, results:NSArray) -> Void {
  …
  results = getResult()
}
```

Can I pass the end results of `doTask()` to the function argument `results` and access it outside the function scope?

Comment: Aren't you missing an asterisk in your Obj-C code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26507349/335858

Comment: in swift you may have void returning functions too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, you need to mark a parameter as being `inout`; that is, you can write to it in the function and the changes to the variable take affect outside the function scope:

```
func doTask(id: Int, inout results: NSArray) -> Void {
    // …

    results = NSArray()
}
```

Then to call the function, you need to pass a valid variable of that type, and append it with an ampersand:

```
var results: NSArray()
doTask(4, &results)
```