# Swift 2 - Are arrays being copied during setting?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have such class setup. In my methods I want to work with specific array depending on what parameter is passed. My question is : is "array" variable a copy of selected array or a reference to it? If it is a copy, how does one pass a reference to an array? I don't want to copy it becuase it is quite long.

I heard that in times of Swift 1 arrays were copied only when needed (compiler decides when). How things are now in Swift 2?

```
class ... {
private var currentVertexes = [CCVertex]()
private var mainVertexes : [CCVertex]!
private var leftVertexes : [CCVertex]!
private var rightVertexes : [CCVertex]!
private var topVertexes : [CCVertex]!
private var bottomVertexes : [CCVertex]!

...
internal func method(var factor: Float) {

    let array = factor < 0.0 ? leftVertexes : rightVertexes
...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Pass array by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250938/swift-pass-array-by-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are value types, but use copy-on-write to prevent unnecessary copies when you merely access them in a read-only fashion (see [SwiftDocs](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/type/Array/))

So if the rest of your method only reads from the array, then you don't need to worry about copies (irrespective of whether `CVVertex` is a struct or a class).

Comment: Is that trust-worthy source?

Comment: It's not an official Apple source, but it's a very well known open source community project that includes content generated from Swift itself

Comment: Ok, i will mark your post as answer just becuase i really hope things are that way

Comment: Cool! It definitely is that way, here's an Apple link that mentions it too: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Depends on whether `CCVertex` is a struct or a class. If it's a struct it will be copied, not if it's a class.

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Sa) (and with good examples too):

> Copying an array also copies all of the elements of that array that are value types. This means that changing one of the elements of an array does not change the elements of any of the copies of the array
>
> If the elements in an array are instances of classes, changing the class does affect other copies, because classes have reference semantics