# Swift Object reference to array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I probably missed an important information about swift. I have a map contains a key / swift array pair. I changed the array and the array inside the map was not changed. Could someone explain what is going on? Thanks!

```
var map = [String:[String]]()
var list = [String]()
map["list"] = list //output: "["list": []]\n"
print(map)

list.append("test")
print(list)  //output: "["test"]\n"
print(map)   //output: "["list": []]\n"
```

Comment: Swift arrays are passed by value, i.e. copied around. You have to set it back into the map, or use some kind of reference wrapper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250938/swift-pass-array-by-reference

Comment: I've used wrapper classes to get this functionality. I do wonder if there is a way to use a pointer to the array and then create an array from the pointer some place else though.

Comment: There is no way to use a pointer for the array in Swift, as it doesn't work that way.

Comment: "There is no way to use a pointer for the array in Swift" That is not entirely true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've been told, these (dictionaries and arrays) are [value types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366050/341994). So in general the technique you're looking for is simply to take the array out of the dictionary, modify it, and put it back in again:

```
var map = [String:[String]]()
map["list"] = [String]()

var list = map["list"]!
list.append("test")
map["list"] = list
```

However, there's another way: you can get a sort of pointer to the array inside the dictionary, but only if you use a function with an `inout` parameter. For example:

```
var map = [String:[String]]()
map["list"] = [String]()

func append(s : String, inout to arr : [String]) {
    arr += [s]
}
append("test", to: &(map["list"]!))
```

That's actually just a notation for the same thing, but if you're going to do a lot of this you might prefer it.

Comment: And see this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECreferenceTypes

Answer (score 2):

### Class

Let's suppose we have a type that is a `class` in Swift:

```
class MyClass {
    var a:Int
    init(i:Int) {
        a = i
    }
}

let aClass = MyClass(i: 10)
var bClass = aClass
bClass.a = 20
aClass.a // 20
aClass.a = 30
bClass.a // 30
```

Here we see pointer-style behaviour: aClass and bClass are pointing at the same object. If you change a property value in one of them then both change, because they are the same.

### Struct

The behaviour changes when a `struct` is used, as can be seen here:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var a:Int
    init(i:Int) {
        a = i
    }
}
let aStruct = MyStruct(i: 10)
var bStruct = aStruct
bStruct.a = 20
aStruct.a // 10
```

With a `struct` (and an `enum`) instead of there being a single instance and multiple pointers to that instance, a new instance is created when we assign the value to a new instance. It is a copy of the original and they are independent of one another.

### Array type

Since the Swift Array type is a `struct` it has the behaviour of copying rather than pointing. While `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` remain classes (as in ObjC) and so have the pointing behaviour of a `class`.

### Making a struct behave like a class

You've already seen others post about inout properties, and you can also use computed variables to partially replicate the behaviour of a pointer:

```
struct MyStruct {
    lazy var map = [String:[String]]()
    var list:[String] {
        mutating get {
            if map["list"] == nil {
                map["list"] = [String]()
            }
            return map["list"]!
        }
        set {
            map["list"] = newValue
        }
        
    }
}

var mS = MyStruct()
mS.list = ["test"]
mS.map // ["list": ["test"]]
mS.list // ["test"]
```

While outside a type instance you might do the following:

```
var map = [String:[String]]()
var list = [String]()
var appendToList = { (a:String) in
    list.append(a)
    map["list"] = list
}
appendToList("test") // list and map["list"] are both updated
```

Answer (score 1):

Array in Swift is defined as a struct, i.e. a value type. When you assign another variable to another variable of value type, it creates a copy of that second variable:

```
map["list"] = list   // store a **copy** of list into map
```

To see the difference between value and reference type, change your array to its ObjectiveC cousin, `NSMutableArray`, which is of reference type:

```
var map = [String: NSMutableArray]()
var list = NSMutableArray()
map["list"] = list

list.addObject("test")

print(map)   // ["list": (test)]
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Code Different](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538939/code-different) says, Arrays in Swift are structs, so you are storing a copy of the array.

If you really want to keep using Swift arrays, I recommend to fill the array "list" first and then copy to "map". That should work for you.