# Swift: Why does ternary operator create copy of an array instead of referencing the original?

Tags: ios, swift, reference, copy, ternary-operator

I just noticed some behavior I didn't expect when using Swift's ternary operator. I have two arrays, and depending on a conditional, I want to append to one or the other. But instead of appending to my class-level array, it just appends to the local copy.

I assumed since I am using arrays of custom class objects, it would reference them instead of creating a copy.

Example Scenario:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var maleArray: [Person] = []
    var femaleArray: [Person] = []

    func append(person: Person) {
        var arrayToAppendTo = person.isMale ? maleArray : femaleArray
        arrayToAppendTo.append(person)
    }
}
```

At the end of the call to `append(person:)`, `arrayToAppendTo` has a count of 1, but both `maleArray` and `femaleArray` are empty.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Note: I know I can just do an `if/else` to append, but I am curious to know why this behavior occurs.

Comment: Why do you need two different arrays? Just use a single one and filter it if needed

Comment: the reason is that arrays are value types. https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

Comment: @LeoDabus My actual scenario isn't as simple. I wanted to break it down to a simpler example for sake of the post.

Comment: Anyway it will make a copy of it

Comment: @luk2302 Ah that makes sense. I was approaching it from what is contained in the array, not the array itself. Thanks.

Comment: The strange is that arrays are always considered a reference type

Comment: Similar question / answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507096/swift-how-to-assign-a-variable-by-reference-not-by-value

Comment: ternary operator is not the cause even if you assigned it directly it will make a copy

Comment: @Sh_Khan to pass it as a reference you would need to make the array a property of a class and pass the class instance

Comment: @LeoDabus sure class will wrap it around it's reference type

Comment: @JakeG you should take a look at Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns more specifically singleton https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID177

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I know it's value type in swift , try it in c++ and you'll know

Comment: @Sh_Khan so you wanted to say that generally arrays are implemented as reference types in other languages, not that "arrays are always considered a reference type".. you got to be careful with words, somebody might take you seriously (just as I just did)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ  yes, this what i meant we always know primitive types to be value types not collections as common in most languages

Comment: @Sh_Khan yeah, it is a bit counter-intuitive, I remember that when I first stumbled upon it I was too a bit puzzled about what's going

Answer (score 2):

Swift arrays are value types, so a new copy is made each time.
If you want to still use a ternary operator, change it to:

```
person.isMale ? maleArray.append(person) : femaleArray.append(person)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @luk2302 stated, arrays are [value types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) (they are structs - see its [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) that says it is a generic structure, and all structs are value types). That simply means that if you create a "reference" to an existing array, it will be copied - then if append to/remove from, or otherwise modify the array using the new variable, the modifications will not be made on the original array.

It has nothing to do with ternary operator. You can test it by changing:

```
var arrayToAppendTo = person.isMale ? maleArray : femaleArray
```

to

```
var arrayToAppendTo = maleArray
```

And you'll see it still will not modify the original array in the property.

So in conclusion, you will not be able to use an intermediate variable, and you will have to directly access the array you want to change.

Either using solution suggested by @MehulParmar or simply `if-else`:

```
if person.isMale {
    maleArray.append(person)
} else {
    femaleArray.append(person)
}
```

Comment: this causes an unnecessary CoW, better to just skip the intermediate variable

Comment: @Alexander that's true.. I did not suggest solution, just provided an explanation

Comment: @Alexander since OP was not asking about solution, but explanation why does this happen...