# Swift array modify by reference

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have the following Swift code

```
 public class VisualLayer {

     public var layerItems:[VisualLayerItems] = []

 }
```

And in the code, I try to add/remove elements to layerItems as follows:

```
 var layerItems = visualLayer.layerItems
 layerItems.insert(item, at: index)
```

The problem is this does not modify *layerItems* array of *visualLayer*. Rather it creates a copy of array *layerItems* and inserts *item* to it. I am not sure why *layerItems* is not modified by reference despite being part of a class?

Comment: Because the property is a struct so your local variable will contain a copy. Update the property directly instead.

Comment: I have this thing in many parts of the code. Is there a better fix?

Comment: What do you mean “better fix”, updating the property directly is the proper way to handle this? You could of course assign the variable back to the property once you are done modifying it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson is right. If you're insistent on requiring a reference, you can check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57564098/9333764

Comment: Worse, what if I return some element of array in a function which then modifies the property of that element. Now it's unpredictable whether the property of the element in original array has been updated or not.

Comment: Deepak, understanding and using the difference between the two paradigms, is a very basic thing in programming.  Both have advantages and disadvantages. It's a basic aspect of programming that you need to be able to use both, and understand the difference between a class and a struct. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

An array is a struct and every time you pass it around, Swift makes copy of the array. If you want to edit the layerItems in the VisualLayer class, you should pass the whole class, this is passed by reference, and the edit the layerItems. If you pass the layerItems in the class to a function, use inout to pass the original array.