# How to use a value type object as a reference type?

Tags: swift

In my model, I have some arrays:

```
var thisArray = [Object]
var thatArray = [Object]
var anotherArray = [Object]
```

In my view controller, I want to switch on a value to determine which array I will append to:

```
var whichArray: [Object]!
switch someValue {
    case .thisArray: whichArray = thisArray
    case .thatArray: whichArray = thatArray // "He went thatArray!"
    case .anotherArray: whichArray = anotherArray
}
whichArray.append(object)
```

But of course this won't work because Array is a value type.

Is there a way to do this? Of course I could do the following:

```
switch someValue {
    case .thisArray: thisArray.append(object)
    case .thatArray: thatArray.append(object)
    case .anotherArray: anotherArray.append(object)
}
```

But that is so inelegant and redundant! And if there's other more complex things going on in the surrounding code, then it's especially so.

Is there a solution here? Is it possible to create a reference to a value type?

PS. Even better, though really its own question, is if I could use the *name* of the case (e.g., "thisArray" for `someValue = .thisArray`) to set the array, by name (i.e., avoid the whole switch statement and just say `objectName.append(object)` or something like that) but as far as I know this isn't a thing. Or maybe this IS possible? And maybe it's my birthday?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Pass array by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250938/swift-pass-array-by-reference)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24252394/2976878) to the above linked Q&A – you can always just create a `class` wrapper.

Comment: Jonathan, if you receive an answer that helps you on Stack Overflow, you should accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of it to turn it green. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would typically recommend solving this with closures. It's more powerful and safer. For example:

```
let append: (Object) -> Void

switch someValue {
case .thisArray: append = { thisArray.append($0) }
case .thatArray: append = { thatArray.append($0) }
case .anotherArray: append = { anotherArray.append($0) }
}

append(object)
```

(It would be ideal here to just say `append = thisArray.append`, but you can't do that in Swift today. It's a "partial application of a mutating function" and that's not currently legal.)

Comment: Is there another benefit of this approach compared to the OP's second version (immediately appending to the arrays inside the switch), except for the fact that this lets you append multiple times to the same "chosen" array with `append(object)`? A safety benefit? Or do you just mean *safer* compared to the `UnsafeMutablePointer` approach?

Comment: @Keiwan as an approach, it allows you to do any operation. So it doesn't have to be specifically an array. It could add to multiple arrays, insert into a set, or be a no-op.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Arrays` are *value types* - as you have said yourself - they can't be passed around (or assigned) as a reference. One solution would be to create a wrapper class for the `Array` which itself would then be a *reference type*. You can then assign this wrapper class instead of the arrays themselves.

Now, given that you also said you might prefer to access the `Arrays` by the name and completely get rid of the `switch` you could change your design to storing `thisArray`, `thatArray` and `anotherArray` in a `Dictionary`, with the keys being the different values for `someValue`.

This way you could simply append to the desired array with:

```
arrayDict[someValue]?.append(object)
```

*(Given that you've properly set up the dictionary beforehand)*

Like this for example:

```
enum Value {
    case thisArray
    case thatArray
    case anotherArray
}

var arrayDict = [
    Value.thisArray : [String](),
    Value.thatArray : [String](),
    Value.anotherArray : [String]()
]

arrayDict[.thatArray]?.append("Some String.")
```

*For the sake of creating a short working example I've replaced `Object` with `String` but that obviously doesn't matter.*

Answer (score 1):

Even though Swift was designed to reduce pointer operations, pointers are still available:

```
var thisArray = [1,2,3]
var thatArray = [4,5,6]
var anotherArray = [7,8,9]
var ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<[Int]>

let someValue = 2
switch someValue {
    case 1: ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer(&thisArray)
    case 2: ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer(&thatArray)
    default: ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer(&anotherArray)
}

ptr.pointee.append(42)
print(thatArray) // [4,5,6,42]
```

A minor annoyance with this is that you have to call `ptr.pointee` to access the target array. If you assign the pointee to another variable (i.e. `let whichArray = ptr.pointee`), any modification to `whichArray` won't be reflected in the original array.

(I had to change your `Object` type to `Int` so that it runs in the IBM Swift Sandbox)

Comment: This is somewhat dangerous IMO. There's no promise that the arrays are still valid after the end of the switch statement. Swift is allowed to release them after the last time they are directly referenced. If you know their lifetime through other means (if they're known to be properties of the current object), then you can get away with it, but I don't think you have any promises here. You should really be using `withExtendedLifetime`, which makes it a lot more complicated.

Comment: "If you assign the pointee to another variable (i.e. let whichArray = ptr.pointee), any modification to whichArray won't be reflected in the original array." I found this question, and your answer, exactly because of this problem. I had (stupidly?) assumed I could assign the pointee value to a variable and avoid having to say .pointee this and .pointee that when working on a struct with almost 10 fields. Is there any way of avoiding that rather ugly syntax?