# Passing a value type as reference in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, pass-by-reference, value-type

I have my model implemented as `structs` in Swift 3.0. Several of these `structs` have delegates that should be able to modify the model depending on the user's actions.

However, when I pass the `struct` to the `delegate` method, it gets copied.

How do you solve this? Can you force the compiler to pass this `struct` as a reference, or the only option is to use a `class`?

Comment: The whole point of using `struct` in the first place is that this is desirable behavior. It preserves the immutability of the data. `inout` can achieve this, but it's not recommended in the general case. Why exactly is the copying an issue?

Comment: Then how do you modify the model from a Controller? If you have a delegate method that passes the model as it's first paramter, as usual in Cocoa, how can the delegate (usually a controller) modify the _real_ model, not a copy of it?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to use a value type object as a reference type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41833469/2976878)

Comment: @cfischer Modifying a model is the controllers job, not the delegates. The controller should ask the delegate how to modify the model, and then modify it itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct`s are always passed by value. The whole point of using a `struct` is to have it behave as a value type. If you need delegation (which usually implies mutable state), you should be using a class.

If you *really really* need to, you could force pass-by-reference by using an `inout` parameter, but that is not recommended in general. You could also use a [box type](https://github.com/robrix/Box) to simulate passing by reference. But, in general, you should just use a class if you need reference behavior.

Comment: *Everything*, regardless of type, is always passed by value, when not using `inout`.

Comment: Well, technically yes, but since when you pass a class reference you are actually passing a reference by value, it pretty much acts effectively the same as pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of using struct in the first place is that this is desirable behavior. It preserves the immutability of the data. `inout` can achieve this, but it's not recommended in the general case.

```
protocol Delegate {
    func callback(_ oldValue: Int) -> Int
}

struct IncrementerDelegate: Delegate {
    let step: Int

    func callback(_ oldValue: Int) -> Int {
        return oldValue + step
    }
}

struct Model {
    var i = 0
}

class Controller {
    var model = Model()
    var delegate: Delegate

    init(delegate: Delegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    // To be called externally, such as by a button
    func doSomething() {
        // Delegate determains new value, but it's still the
        // controller's job to perform the mutation.
        model.i = delegate.callback(model.i)
    }
}

let delegate = IncrementerDelegate(step: 5)
let controller = Controller(delegate: delegate)
print(controller.model.i)
controller.doSomething() // simulate button press
print(controller.model.i)








protocol CrappyDelegate {
    func callback(_ model: inout Model)
}

struct CrappyIncrementerDelegate: CrappyDelegate {
    let step: Int

    func callback(_ model: inout Model) {
        model.i = 9999999
        // Just hijacked the models value,
        // and the controller can't do anything about it.
    }
}

class VulnerableController {
    var model = Model()
    var delegate: CrappyDelegate

    init(delegate: CrappyDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    // To be called externally, such as by a button
    func doSomething() {
        // Controller leaks entire model, and has no control over what happens to it
        delegate.callback(&model)
    }
}

let crappyDelegate = CrappyIncrementerDelegate(step: 5)
let vulnerableController = VulnerableController(delegate: crappyDelegate)
print(controller.model.i)
controller.doSomething() // simulate button press
print(controller.model.i) // model hijacked
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass by reference, you should generally use a `class` not a `struct`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html states:

> You can use both classes and structures to define custom data types to
>   use as the building blocks of your program’s code.
>
> However, structure instances are always passed by value, and class
>   instances are always passed by reference. This means that they are
>   suited to different kinds of tasks. As you consider the data
>   constructs and functionality that you need for a project, decide
>   whether each data construct should be defined as a class or as a
>   structure.