# Pass Array By Reference [Swift 3 Xcode 8]

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have created a bullet class, and I want it to hold an attribute called locatedInArray. locatedInArray stores a reference of the array that the bullet is stored in within the GameScene class. The only problem is that when I add print statements, it shows that the locatedInArray has different values when compared to the actual array in the game scene. Is there anyway to pass the array by reference instead of value?

The array being passed through a function call to the bullet instance.

```
bullet.shoot(from: self.mainCharacter, to: "right", fromPercentOfWidth: 0.5, fromPercentOfHeight: 0.65, addToArray: &playerBulletArray, inScene: self)
```

Array being assigned as attribute inside bullet object.

```
func shoot(from character: SKSpriteNode, to direction: String, fromPercentOfWidth xPercent: CGFloat, fromPercentOfHeight yPercent: CGFloat, addToArray array: inout[SKBulletsNode?], inScene scene: GameScene) {

    self.gameScene = scene
    self.locatedInArray = array
}
```

Comment: Why does a bullet care about which array has a defence to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you create a class which contains the `SKBulletsNode` array as a property and pass a single one of those objects into the function?

like this:

```
class BulletArray {
    var bullets : [SKBulletsNode]?
}

func shoot(from character: SKSpriteNode, to direction: String, fromPercentOfWidth xPercent: CGFloat, fromPercentOfHeight yPercent: CGFloat, addToArray array: inout BulletArray , inScene scene: GameScene) {
   self.gameScene = scene
   self.locatedInArray = array
}
```

check out this link for more info:
[Swift: Pass array by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250938/swift-pass-array-by-reference)

Comment: Yes, locatedInArray is actually of type [SKBulletsNode?].

Comment: Arrays and Dictionaries in Swift are passed by value, so you must wrap it in a class in order to pass it by reference.

Comment: It would be nicer if there was an easier solution available, but I guess this can work just in case there are not better ways. Thanks though.

Comment: I used a NSMutableArray instead, and that seems to have worked.