# Modifying an array passed as an argument to a function in Swift

Tags: swift

Sorry for the newbie question; I'm still learning. I'm running into some odd behavior and couldn't find any documentation on this. I was wondering if you can help point out what I'm doing wrong here.

Error:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'arr' is a 'let' constant

```
class mySingleton {
    static let sharedInstance = mySingleton()
    private init() {}

    var men = ["bob", "doug"]
    var women = ["alice", "lisa"]

    func removeFirst() {
        self.arr.removeFirst()
    }

    func removeFirstByGender(gender: String) {
        if gender == "men" {
              self.modify(arr: self.men) // <-- error occurs here.
        } else {
              self.modify(arr: self.women) // <-- error occurs here.
        }
    }

    func modify(arr: [String]) {
        arr.removeFirst()
    }
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250938/swift-pass-array-by-reference

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clearly indicate which line of code is causing the error.

Comment: This is an example quite far away from reality because you can access the `arr` **property** directly.

Comment: I would first make one of the arr-arrays an NSArray or rename it to prevent confusion. Then, I guess, the problem is that you can also call class properties without self.property. That means that maybe your function uses the classes arr, not the one in the arguments.

Comment: @vadian my use-case is when I have multiple arrays in a class, and I want a generic function to modify a select array.

Comment: Then provide a real example with your *use-case* or/and a (better) description of your goal.

Comment: @vadian Sure. Updated example code in question.

Comment: Dávid's answer does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change the definition of `modify` to accept an `inout` parameter. By default, function arguments are immutable, but by using the `inout` keyword, you can make them mutable. You also need to pass the argument by reference.

```
func modify( arr: inout [String]) {
    arr.removeFirst()
}
var stringArr = ["a","b"]
modify(arr: &stringArr) //stringArr = ["b"] after the function call
```