# cannot assign through subscript in swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to implement common alghorithm in Swift.

Even though I did not define numbers as a let variable, but I am getting following error:

> cannot assign through subscript: 'numbers' is a 'let' constant
>                   numbers[i] = maxNumber

My Implementation is as follows:

```
func InsertionSort (numbers : [Int]) -> [Int]
{
    var maxNumber  = 0
    var j = 0
    var size = numbers.count-1

    for (i,number) in numbers.enumerated()
    {
        j = i + 1
        for index in j...size
        {
            if numbers[index] > number
            {
                maxNumber = numbers[index]
                numbers[index] = numbers[i]
                // error is thrown in the following line
                numbers[i] = maxNumber
            }
        }
    }

    return numbers
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying an array passed as an argument to a function in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640752/modifying-an-array-passed-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-swift)

Comment: Function parameters are constant by default.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Although that question's answer works here, I don't think that is the best solution in this situation.

Comment: @Sweeper depending on what he does with the returned value he can either use your answer or `inout` parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot assign through subscript: 'dict' is a 'let' constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310863/cannot-assign-through-subscript-dict-is-a-let-constant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters are immutable by default. To make a parameter mutable, you need to add an `inout` modifier.

However, seeing that your method *returns* an array, you probably don't want the parameter to be modified as well. You should instead make a copy of the parameter, modify that, and return the copy:

```
func InsertionSort (numbers : [Int]) -> [Int]
{
    var maxNumber  = 0
    var j = 0
    let size = numbers.count-1
    var numbersCopy = numbers // <------ note this line

    for (i,number) in numbers.enumerated()
    {
        j = i + 1
        for index in j...size
        {
            if numbers[index] > number
            {
                maxNumber = numbers[index]

                // note how I modified the copy here
                numbersCopy[index] = numbers[i]
                numbersCopy[i] = maxNumber
            }
        }
    }

    return numbersCopy
}
```

Comment: Yes I missed that